# MySQL does it matter which column I COUNT() by

Tags: mysql

I've been wondering about this for quite some time. Is it better to do this where the primary key `ticket_id` is counted:

```
SELECT COUNT(ticket_id) 
FROM tickets
WHERE ticket_country_id = 238
```

Or to do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(ticket_country_id) 
FROM tickets
WHERE ticket_country_id = 238
```

In this case ticket_country_id is an indexed foreign key, but we could also assume it's just a non-indexed column (perhaps the answer would be different for non-indexed columns)

**In other words, does it matter that I am calling on another column for the COUNT()?**

Obviously the performance saving would probably be small, but I like to do things the best way.

Comment: No It does not matter.
it will always give you same count.
it counts even if record is NULL

Comment: @Priyanshu I'm more referring to performance issues. The speed of query execution.

Comment: @AmyNeville, why don't you want to use classical: count(*) or count(1) ?

Comment: @MaxU well I feel like count(*) would call on all columns. I hadn't considered count(1) though - although that might require mysql to create a column of 1's? to be clear I deal with tables that can get into the 10's of millions sometimes so these small performance things are important.

Comment: @AmyNeville, no, you don't need "a column of 1's" - count(*) and count(*) are the same thing, unless you use MyISAM where count(*) is bit  more optimized . You may want to read this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count

Comment: Amy, what i know is count ( * ) and count(column), gives different result when there is Null records. Count(*) returns all rows with No-Null or Null values, where count(column) will return number of rows having no-null values .  You ca  read a comparison of performance here , https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/04/10/count-vs-countcol/

Comment: Thanks guys, definitely worth a read :)

Comment: Functionally it most certainly can matter. COUNT(*) counts all rows that meet the conditions of the query. Any specified column is tested for being NULL or not, and if NULL it is not counted. i.e. If you want all rows counted don't specify any column, otherwise the specified column is tested (and that could be a different result)

Comment: @Priyanshu : You're wrong about COUNT always giving you the same count even if a record value is NULL. If you use COUNT(column) and "column" contains NULL values, those NULLs will NOT be counted. On the other hand, if you use COUNT(*) all records, including ones with NULL values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,it can matter. Select count(*) allows the DB to use whatever resources make sense and are most efficient. It can do as table scan, use a primary key or other index to answer your question.

Count(something-else) means count the non null values. Again, the DB can use several methods such as indexes if such thing are available but you are then asking a different question.

As is often the case with SQL it's better to ask the question you want answers to than play silly games trying to game the system for a few milliseconds here and there.

That helps your future colleagues too by clearly stating the thing you are trying to do.